# Without enums, what alternative to a <string, TValue> Dictionary can yield compile-time errors?

Tags: c#, data-structures

*First, I apologize for my lack of knowledge, about how to make this relevant to many people (many neophytes, anyway) - my only programming experience is with [Unity](http://answers.unity3d.com/users).  Not [that Unity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650320.aspx), which I just heard about while searching this site.*

I want to know if there's a better data structure than a class, for this sort of thing:

```
class Cameras {
    public Camera left, right; 
} Cameras cameras;
```

I find myself creating a bunch of classes (they're not all containers for only two objects), which seem like they would be better served by a Dictionary - except, I want have compile-time errors if I screw up spelling, which won't happen with strings as a key.  I also don't want to just use arrays or lists, because I don't want to have to remember what int goes with what object.  I could create enums for each class like this, and switch to Dictionaries instead of classes, but that sounds ridiculous to me(*).  Is there some alternative?  It seems to me that what I need is a structure that lets me define something like an enum that gets associated with an Array or List, but I bet you'll have a better idea.  ;-)

(*) And yet, from the information you all have provided, that's apparently the model that exists.  This seems like a fundamental issue to have addressed, to me, and I wonder why it hasn't been.  I don't know if the syntax below has been used for something else, but it seems reasonable to me.

```
public class StereoCameraSystem : MonoBehaviour {
    // You populate cameras in the Unity Editor GUI.
    // Have the language implement something like this...
    [SerializeField] Camera [] {left, right} cameras;

    // define StereoCameraSide enum here

    void ListCameras () {
        Debug.Log(cameras[left]);  // ...so you can use this...
        Debug.Log(cameras[StereoCameraSide.Left]);  //...and avoid this.
    }
}
```

Comment: Your title seems to be asking one question (strong type checking when using Dictionaries), but the body seems to be asking a different question (small class profusion).

Comment: _"Without enums"_ - using `enum`s would be a great solution to your problem. Why is it not an option for you?

Comment: I've edited the question.  Hopefully that clarifies things.  From what I'm hearing here, and all that I've learned, I think that the answer to my question is, "nothing useful".  I just have a hard time believing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swift's tuples solved the problem. C# will have to alter its tuples to be like Swift's, before it is a viable language to use, when this feature is needed.

```
let cameras: (left: Camera, right: Camera)
```

Answer (score 3):

Dictionaries don't have to be indexed by strings.  You can have a `Dictionary<MyEnum, MyClass>`, and index by enum.  You'll then get full compiler error checking if you mistype the enum identifier when looking something up in the dictionary.

Comment: But as far as I know, that would require creating an enum for every class, unless there were other things that conformed to the enum, which doesn't happen often for me.  Am I wrong on that somehow?

Comment: In place of an enum, you could index by the type itself:  Dictionary<Type, MyBaseClass>, assuming you have multiple subclasses and you only want one instance of each in the dictionary.  Access like this  obj = dictionary[typeof(FooClass)]  The key thing with Dictionary<key,value> is you can index on any object.  String is an object, enum is an object, and type is an object.

Comment: Back to the enum: you'd define an enum type for each dictionary that lists all the possible index values you want to use with that dictionary, and that enum contains one value for each object you want to put into that dictionary.

Comment: Good information, thanks.  (Comment would get an upvote if I had that ability.) But no, the Cameras are not subclasses, nor are you allowed to subclass Unity Objects anyway.

Answer (score 2):

```
enum CameraKind {
    Left,
    Right
}

var cameras = new Dictionary<CameraKind, Camera> {
    { CameraKind.Left, leftCamera }, // shortcut for Add method
    { CameraKind.Right, rightCamera }
};

DoSomethingWith (cameras [CameraKind.Left]);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write clean and readable C# code, then you just have to write a lot of (sometimes long) class declarations. This is the way object-oriented programming works.

An alternative solution for your problem - if you're happy to sacrifice some readability - is to use tuples. Tuples are data structures that group two (or more) things with possibly different types in a safe way. To represent two cameras, you could write:

```
// Wrap two cameras into tuple data structure
Tuple<Camera, Camera> cameras = Tuple.Create(firstCamera, secondCamera);

// Get the first camera
cameras.Item1
// Get the second camera
cameras.Item2
```

The only unfortunate thing is that you'll have to use `Item1` and `Item2` instead of nice names (like `Left` and `Right`). Tuples come from functional programming, which often gives you a lighter programming style - if you want, you can check out F#, which is a functional language for .NET.

Comment: My problem with the class definition is that there will only be one instance of the class, and that it only stores what equates to an array.  Is this a common way of doing things?  (An alternative would be to store two Cameras called leftCamera and rightCamera.)  The whole point of the method I've been employing is readability, so Tuples don't sound like a good match.

Answer (score 0):

In C# 4.0 it should look like this (note that it has no intellisense support):

```
dynamic cameras = new ExpandoObject();
cameras.left = new Camera(); // set the property to initialize it
Debug.Log(cameras.left);
```